# Unable to set Debug pointer by single click on runnable line and unable to see tooltip next to the @Text inside the test class in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, junit4

I suddenly started getting following 2 issues after I triggered clean install on my projects.

1. I am unable to set Debug pointer (orange debug icon does not come - next to current line number) via single 
   click on runnable Java class's line
2. unable to see tool-tip (green arrow to run given test case - next to current line number) next to the @Text inside the test class in IntelliJ.

I have tried reading over the net for the possible solution for over 2 days now, but these 2 issues are not related to other posts available. I am posting here since I still do not have a solution.

Solutions that I have tried:

1. Invalidate Casche and Restart
2. Reimport All Projects and do a fresh mvn clean install
3. Remove unwanted plugins

Other details,

Junit framework - junit4
Source code - Java

Anything regarding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called **Gutter Icons**. To enable these on file level go to **View -> Active Editor -> Show Gutter Icons**.

& To enable these on all files at once, go to **Settings -> Editor -> General -> Gutter Icons -> Select the checkbox which says 'Show Gutter Icons'**

I might have mistakenly deselected this option. So happy to have these Gutter Icons back now. Hope this helps someone who is new to IntelliJ like me.